# how to pass url parameters in a http request in angular 4

Tags: angular, httprequest

How to make get request by passing parameters? I tried this but getting 404 error

```
getOrderbyOrderNo() {

        this.orderno = this.cookie_service.get('key');

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('orderno', this.orderno );
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append("someParamKey", this.orderno )

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/View/orders', { headers: headers, params: params })


    }
```

output

```
ERROR 
Object { _body: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot GET /View/orders</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: {…}, type: 2, url: "http://localhost:8080/View/orders" }
```

Comment: you are using httpclient or http ?

Comment: show your serverside method also ...if it working fine then do change as given in answer

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there are two ways by which you can send params with http request.

1. By appending it to URL like this -

   ```
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/View/orders/'+this.orderno, { headers: headers  })
   ```
2. Another way is, If you are using `httpclient` then you can send params in the options like this-

   ```
    let httpParams = new HttpParams()
       .set('orderno', this.orderno);
   ```

For more about this read out here

- https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-httpclient-get-example#parameters

In `get` type of request there is no body part of request so you have to append your params in your URL i.e params or query params. or using second way in options.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer may i KNow? why Downvote?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using httpclient then you should do this

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = Params.append('firstParameter', parameters.valueOne);
params = Params.append('secondParameter', parameters.valueTwo);
return this._HttpClient.get(`${API_URL}/api/logs`, { params: params })
```

or you can create object of params

```
export interface GetParams {
  firstParameter?: string;
  secondParameter?: string;
   ..more param you want 
} 


Const getParamsobj : GetParams = {
  firstParameter: 'value',
  secondParameter: 'value'
  ..other params
}
return this._HttpClient.get(`${API_URL}/api/logs`, { params: getParamsobj })
```

Comment: where does this `params` will add at the time of `httpCall` ?

Comment: @PardeepJain - not getting you

Comment: I mean to say is your method is different from my? or after exceution it will append with URL?

Comment: @PardeepJain - it will append parameter to url, so no need to do manually as you did

Comment: so Basically OUR answers are same, with different method :)

Comment: @PardeepJain - its not same in terms of effort, what is list of parameter get increased , in your case you need to create long querystring , in my case just add to list

Comment: yes , But I posted answer only considering OP's use case, still don't know why got downvote?

Comment: @PardeepJain - you are complicating things, which can be easily done...follow good practice to make you code maintainable ...:)

Comment: Got your point, thanks :) but still Downvote is never a way to tell this whoever did this, just put it comment there that this is something wrong etc. anyways thanks :)

Comment: @PardeepJain - most of the time you get downvote when solution is wrong or not upto the mark, better to delete answer and see who given good answer, thats process of learning , earning points is easy but earning knowledge is more important

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameters like this:

```html
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/View/orders?someParamKey=xyz&anotherParam=abc
', { headers: headers})
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameters and headers is different in `HttpClient` since they're immutable, If you want to pass the parameter you should use `HttpParams`.

`{ params: new HttpParams().set('name', term) }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

import this packages to your class:

```
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
```

inject `HttpClient` like this:

```
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
```

send request:

```
    let url = "your url";

    let Params = new HttpParams();
    Params = Params.append('param1', value1);
    Params = Params.append('param2', value2);

    let header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    header = header.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

    return this._http.get(url , { params: Params, headers: header })
        .map((response: Response) => {
        });
```

Comment: @rina what is the problem ? why un accept my answer?

Comment: parameters are passing but showing all table data, it's not appending with the url